# Why do light edges appear on transparent PNGs online?

Tags: html, css, png

Everytime I try to use transparent PNG images on sites, white edges keep appearing around the images, seen in the photo below. How come this is happening, and how do I stop this from happening?

[image: 1]

(I'm currently using Google Chrome 27.0.1453.116)

Comment: How did you create the PNG? What compression (ie PNG24?) are you using?

Comment: Is that a screenshot of the issue - it isn't transparent?  How about attaching the actual image?

Comment: @kobaltz: It's actually an AI file opened in Photoshop and saved as PNG. I saved them at a big width and height for retina display compatibility.

Those white spots mostly occur whenever I scale them down using CSS, and I'm forced to use -webkit-optimize-contrast on it, but it leaves a very unsettling effect when scaled really small.

Answer (score 4):

This was driving me so crazy too, I had to sign up to answer it so no-one else feels that frustration...

It appears to be down to the image-render that the browser is using to resize those transparent PNGs that's adding a light edge to it.

I've found adding the following css properties to the image element (or if it's a background image, the element itself) fixes the issue for me in Chrome and Firefox:

```
img, div.with-resized-background {
      image-rendering : -webkit-optimize-contrast
      image-rendering : optimizeQuality
}
```

You can read about more options here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/image-rendering

Answer (score 2):

Late answer but this works:

```
/* applies to GIF and PNG images; avoids blurry edges */
img[src$=".gif"], img[src$=".png"] {
    image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;         /* Firefox */
    image-rendering:   -o-crisp-edges;         /* Opera */
    image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast;/* Webkit (non-standard naming) */
    image-rendering: crisp-edges;
    -ms-interpolation-mode: nearest-neighbor;  /* IE (non-standard property) */
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/image-rendering

Here is another link as well which talks about browser support:

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/i/image-rendering/